# Dog barking while alone in house

Tags: dogs, training

My neighbour is at work all day. while he is out his dog constantly barks. How can he train it not to bark while alone in the house?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like separation anxiety, the dog would need some training and depending on severity it may never go away without the help of some calming medications.

Things he can try first would be:

- Vigorous exercise before he leaves for the day, this will make him more likely to want to sleep.
- Reward the dog before he leaves by giving him foraging toys (i.e toys filled with food/treats).
- Thundershirt - it's a vest that essentially hugs the dog making him feel safe.
- DAP collar or spray - this is a scent that helps keep dogs calm.
- Doggie daycare or have someone pet-sit at home when the owners away.
- Bring the dog with him to work if it's possible.
- Speak with a behaviorist about counter-conditioning his fear response to leaving.

Purchasing another dog will not make him stop barking, he misses his master and not another dog (a lot of the time you'll end up with 2 dogs going nuts).

If all fails then he can try some medications such as [Kalmaid](https://nutriscience.ie/product/kalmaid-dog-calming-supplement-copy/) or [Fluoxetine](http://www.veterinarypartner.com/Content.plx?P=A&S=0&C=0&A=2742). Kalmaid is non-prescription so you can pick it up at your vet without the need of seeing a veterinarian.